# Pandas merge giving error "Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I am trying to do a pandas merge and get the above error from the title when I try to run it. I am using 3 columns to match on whereas just before I do  similar merge on only 2 columns and it works fine.

```
df = pd.merge(df, c, how="left",
        left_on=["section_term_ps_id", "section_school_id", "state"],
        right_on=["term_ps_id", "term_school_id", "state"])
```

columns for the two dataframes

df:

```
Index([u'section_ps_id', u'section_school_id', u'section_course_number', u'secti
on_term_ps_id', u'section_staff_ps_id', u'section_number', u'section_expression'
, u'section_grade_level', u'state', u'sections_id', u'course_ps_id', u'course_sc
hool_id', u'course_number', u'course_schd_dept', u'courses_id', u'school_ps_id',
 u'course_school_id', u'school_name', u'school_abbr', u'school_low_grade', u'sch
ool_high_grade', u'school_alt_school_number', u'school_state', u'school_phone',
u'school_fax', u'school_principal', u'school_principal_phone', u'school_principa
l_email', u'school_asst_principal', u'school_asst_principal_phone', u'school_ass
t_principal_email'], dtype='object')
```

c:

```
Index([u'term_ps_id', u'term_school_id', u'term_portion',
u'term_start_date', u' term_end_date', u'term_abbreviation',
u'term_name', u'state', u'terms_id', u'sch ool_ps_id',
u'term_school_id', u'school_name', u'school_abbr', u'school_low_grad
e', u'school_high_grade', u'school_alt_school_number',
u'school_state', u'school
_phone', u'school_fax', u'school_principal', u'school_principal_phone', u'school
_principal_email', u'school_asst_principal', u'school_asst_principal_phone', u's chool_asst_principal_email'],
dtype='object')
```

Is it possible to merge on three columns like this? Is there anything wrong from the merge call here?

Comment: You seem to have two identical columns `"term_school_id"` in you `c` dataframe... Either delete one or rename to avoid duplicate name.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have a dupe column:

[image]

Comment: How to remove the duplicated column..?

Comment: @user1017373 drop it by index)

Comment: @Rocketq your suggestion should be included in the answer, as it is the actual way of fixing the problem ;)

Answer (score 5):

This Will remove the duplicated columns from the Dataframe

```
df = df[list(df.columns[~df.columns.duplicated()])]
```

Answer (score 3):

To adress the issue of the dupe columns you can either drop the dupe column using [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with smth. like:

```
c = c[~c.columns.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

or adding an additional char to either one of the DataFrames using for example:
`c.columns=[c.columns[i]+str(i) for i in range(len(c.columns))]`

Keep in mind that in this case you must adjust the merging part

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicate columns then:

Upgrade your `pandas` and make sure it’s a version above `1.1.0`.
There’s some problem in broadcasting values in older versions of pandas. I had the same problem but it worked well in google colab and that’s how I found its a problem with older version because colab always uses the latest version of any library.

To upgrade pandas use:

```py
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you aware that this question is almonst 6 years old (and has several answers, including an accepted one)? And are you sure the duplicate problem is solved by simply upgrading?

Comment: @Timus Thanks :)... I have mentioned that this may work IF there are no duplicate columns.

Comment: But the dupes are the problem ... ?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue, though the question is old but may help someone.
We have a python code using python library 0.25 and it works fine but when the code is imported to the pod with python library 1.3.2 it starts throwing below error:-

```
ERROR - Error in line 34 ValueError Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)\nTraceback (most recent call last)
```

Downgrading the version to 0.25 resolves the issue or upgrading the code resolves it.