# Pandas: Merge Buffer Error on Renamed Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merging-data

Unfortunately, I can't share the actual data I'm working with for this question, so bear with me as I try to use a generalized example to help explain the error I'm seeing.

I have two dataframes, which we will call `df_local` and `df_global`, which I need to merge to get a full understanding of the data in my database. `df_global` has about 16 columns, the most relevant of which are: `['observation_id', 'min', 'max']`. `df_local` has 4 columns, `['observation_id', 'local_id', 'min', 'max']`. However, between the two dataframes, the `observation_id` is the same but the `min` and `max` mean different things. In `df_local`, the `min` and `max` are local minima and maxima, while the `min` and `max` in `df_global` is the actual min and max of the whole data set for that observation.

When I merge the two dataframes using the following line of code:

`df = pd.merge(df_global, df_local, on = 'observation_id', how = 'outer')`

I get no errors and `df` returns with the columns `['min_x','max_x', 'min_y','max_y']`. Which is.... fine... except that I want to rename the columns before I do the merge so that I know which one is the local and which one is the global.

HOWEVER, when I rename `df_local`'s columns to `['observation_id', 'local_id', 'local_min', 'local_max']` I get the following error on merge:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

This is similar to [this error here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065133/pandas-merge-giving-error-buffer-has-wrong-number-of-dimensions-expected-1-go), so I checked to make sure I had no duplicate columns across either dataframe. I do not. Again, this error ONLY occurs when I try to rename `df_local`'s columns before doing the merge. When I do not rename the columns, I do not get the error.

I have no idea what's going on and have hunted across the internet for help and even asked the resident python gurus working with this data what might be the problem. We're all stuck.

I apologize for not being able to present actual data to show the error in action, but I hope the description is enough that someone might have a solution.

EDIT:

Here is what I can show of my script.

What works:

```
df = pd.merge(df_global, df_local, on = 'observation_id', how = 'outer')
```

What doesn't work:

```
df_local.columns = ['observation_id', 'local_id', 'local_min', 'local_max']
df = pd.merge(df_global, df_local, on = 'observation_id', how = 'outer')
```

Comment: Can you post the entire script that you are using? It is impossible to debug unless you show us your work so far.

Comment: Yes, I will show what I can.

Comment: Can you post a full traceback of your error? Without more info its hard to debug but I think it has something to do with renaming ob_id and local_id  to the same name again.

Comment: Do you get the same error using the Dataframe.rename method to rename just the columns you care about. e.g. `df_local.rename(index=str, columns={'min': 'local_min', 'max': 'local_max'})`