# Pandas ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

Task:
I am trying to categorize numerical values of age into the ranges 'young', 'adult', and 'elderly' through binning.

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065133/pandas-merge-giving-error-buffer-has-wrong-number-of-dimensions-expected-1-go) with a similar error was asked before but it was not answered.

Is there possibly any other alternatives to performing the intended task?

Here is my code:

```
bins = np.linspace(dataframe['Age'], max(dataframe['Age']), 4)
bins.sort()
group_names = ['young', 'adult', 'elderly']
dataframe['Age-binned'] = pd.cut(
                        dataframe['Age'], bins, 
                        labels = group_names, 
                        include_lowest = True
                        )
```

The error comes from the line:

```
dataframe['Age-binned'] = pd.cut(
                        dataframe['Age'], bins, 
                        labels = group_names, 
                        include_lowest = True
                        )
```

and yields:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

Comment: Can you add part of your dataframe? [Minimal, Repeatable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try bins = np.linspace(min(dataframe['Age']), max(dataframe['Age']), 4)?

Comment: Thanks, it works. Why does this work and my code didn't?

Comment: syntax for  np.linspace(start , stop, size) . start = starting point and stop = where you want the bin to stop.